# What is the meaning of an integral equation for a generator of a finitely generated algebra $R$ over a sub algebra $R^G$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, invariant-theory

I'm working in the following book "Computational invariant theory" second edition by Harm Derksen and Gregor Kemper. The book contains the following theorem on page 72

> Let $R$ be a finitely generated algebra over a Noetherian commutative ring, and let $G$ be a finite group acting by automorphisms on $R$ fixing $K$ elementwise. Then $R^G$ is finitely generated as a $K-$algebra.

Note that $R^G$ denotes the elements of $R$ with are invariant under the action. The proof starts like this

> Let $x_1,...,x_r$ be generators of $R$. The polynomial $$ \prod_{\sigma \in G} (T- \sigma \cdot x_i) = T^m + a_{i,1}T^{m-1} + \dots +  a_{i,m-1}T + a_{i,m} \in R^G[T]$$
> provides an integral equation for $x_i$ over $R^G$.

I searched through the book to find a definition of "an integral equation over $R^G$" but I can't find it. So I was wondering if someone could clarify what the meaning is.

Comment: If $R\subset S$ is an inclusion of rings, an element $x\in S$ is integral over $R$ if it satisfies a monic polynomial over $R$. That is, $x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+a_2x^{n-2}+\cdots=0$ for some $a_i\in R$.

Comment: This just say the ring $R$ is integral over $R^G$; For details, you can read Atiyah: Commutative algebra, Page 68, Exercise 12.